# How to centre a string in toolbar fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following part of XML which generates a toolbar in my profile fragment with a black background and profile written in it.
I'm trying though to center the profile but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:name="com.example.myapp_android.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
```

I tried adding to the `<fragment android:label_gravity = "center" and android:gravity = "center"`
but none of them moved the profile text.

Answer (score 1):

Toolbars can have childview so you can use TextView inside of a toolbar

Use this :

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     >
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Toolbar"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>



    
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```